# CCK Field Table in Database and Content Type

Tags: entities, nodes

I am creating some fields in a Custom Created Content type. What I have already seen as per my experience is that their is a table for each field that I have currently in the Content Type. But now I am adding new fields to that content type from **'Admin -> Content Management -> Content Type -> Edit Custom Content Type -> Manage Fields'**. Here I am creating some fields but I dont get a table for them. Why is CCK not creating tables for these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using CCK with Drupal 6 here...

Unless a field is set to multiple cardinality, or is attached to more than one content type, there won't be a table created for it. Instead, a new column will be created for it in the CCK table for that content type.

For example, if you have a content type called 'page' with a number field called 'field_number', with single cardinality and only attached to the 'page' type, there will be a column called `field_number_value` in the `content_type_page` table; that's where the data is stored.

Comment: Can u also guide me on how do i add a multiple entry field for a single record. Suppose i have content type exam and i need a field subjects which has one to many relation, how can i add this Subjects field to Exam.